# Add "!" to the end of each items they own

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array and I want to use map to add ! to each items

i.e.:

before->items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]

after->items:["ball!","book!","pen!"]

```
const array = [
{
   username: "john",
   team: "red",
   score: 5,
   items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
 },
 {
   username: "becky",
   team: "blue",
   score: 10,
   items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
 },
 {
   username: "susy",
   team: "red",
   score: 55,
   items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
 },
  {
   username: "tyson",
   team: "green",
   score: 1,
   items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

  ];
```

What i try in my JS:

```
  const Plusitems = array.map(user => user.items+'!');
  console.log(Plusitems);
```

Comment: Do you want to construct new arrays, or do you want to mutate the existing arrays?

Comment: I want construct new arrays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over input array using `.map()` and use `Object.assign()` to create updated array of strings.

```js
const data = [
  {username: "john", team: "red", score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]},
  {username: "becky", team: "blue", score: 10, items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]},
  {username: "susy", team: "red", score: 55, items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]},
  {username: "tyson", team: "green", score: 1, items: ["book", "pen"]},
];

const result = data.map(o => Object.assign(o, {items: o.items.map(s => s + "!")}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const array = [{username: "john",team: "red",score: 5,items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]},{username: "becky",team: "blue",score: 10,items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]},{username: "susy",team: "red",score: 55,items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]},{username: "tyson",team: "green",score: 1,items: ["book", "pen"]},];
 
let op = array.map(({items,...rest})=>{
    return {
      ...rest,
      items: items.map( e=> e+'!')
    }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
const array = [{username: "john",team: "red",score: 5,items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]},{username: "becky",team: "blue",score: 10,items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]},{username: "susy",team: "red",score: 55,items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]},{username: "tyson",team: "green",score: 1,items: ["book", "pen"]},];

const trArr = array.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    ele['items'] = ele['items'].map((item) => `${item}!`);
    acc.push(ele);
    return acc;
}, []);
  
console.log(trArr);
```